# Visual calculation puzzle

Tags: cipher, visual, calculation-puzzle

Below are some objects and numbers. Try figure out what they represent and finally replace the question mark.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is 117649

because:

7 is the value for g, which is the first letter of "green", the sum of the values of the letters in the word is 49, and "3" is for "cube", 49^3=117649.
Just like "19" is for "square" refering to squaring 
"[red]" and "[yellow]"

Comment: Yes this is correct :)